# more votes than views

Tags: support, views

[image: screenshot of Judaism.stackexchange.com's homepage showing a question listed as having two votes but one view]

Two votes but one view?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Views are not written to the database instantly.  Views on the site are buffered and then written to the database once a site threshold is reached.

Answer (score 1):

I can't find a text reference, but I heard Jeff Atwood explain on the podcast a couple of weeks ago that the SE engine counts views very conservatively, to avoid multi-counting individuals. If you want to know how many times a page was actually read, it's pretty safe to mentally double the nominal view count.